# Getting undefined method `setTimeout' with selenium webdriver using with ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

Getting error as below :

```
C:\Ruby\Scripts>W9_File_delete_v1.rb
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.30.0/lib/selenium/webdr
iver/common/timeouts.rb:33:in `page_load=': undefined method `setTimeout' for #<
Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0xa3263e4 browser=:firefox> (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Documents and Settings/rakshiar/My Documents/userdata/Ruby/Scrip
ts/W9_File_delete_v1.rb:19:in `<main>'
```

With the below code :

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------
#Creating here Firefox Browser agent to get into the
#file deletion process
#--------------------------------------------------------------
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get "https://demo.com/"

#driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 200 # seconds
pgload = Selenium::WebDriver::Timeouts.new(driver)
pgload.page_load=(300)
```

Can I have help on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to create the `Selenium::WebDriver::Timeouts` object directly. Instead, use the appropriate method from the `driver` object.

```
driver.manage.timeouts.page_load = 300
```

Comment: But what's the wrong with my above? Why that's statement didn't work? clarify please.

Comment: I do not know a lot about the selenium-webdriver internals, but my best guess is that you are initializing a `Selenium::WebDriver::Timeouts` object using a `driver` object. Based on the [api docs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Timeouts.html), it expects a `bridge` object instead. It is usually best to use the public api rather than internal classes.

Comment: Humm! you are right.I have researched on it a lots. Good idea is to use,public methods. :) Thanks for your heads up.